# d3.js v4 error jquery conflict?

Tags: javascript

I have a d3 plot that uses the following script:

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

I get the error:

(index):677 Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined

*I have tried the previous solutions where I save the script locally and add the charset without any luck

I should also say that I can load v3 without issues:

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

But v4 has a function d3.stratify which my visualization uses. I'm hosting this page in a larger enterprise web application where jquery is being loaded. When I host my project separately from the enterprise app (no jquery, just d3) it loads fine.

Is there any way that I can verify this conflict for sure before turning jquery off?

Thanks

Comment: according to https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#other-global-changes, in version 4 d3 no longer exposes itself as a global, instead expecting you to use ES2015 modules

Comment: so i tried using var d3 = require('d3') but that throws even weirder errors. If the script is loaded and I can see it when Inspecting, why can't I access the variables?

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs if you have `requirejs` or ther Commonjs/AMD implementation library in your page.

> The default UMD bundle is now anonymous. No d3 global is exported if AMD or CommonJS is detected. In a vanilla environment, the D3 microlibraries share the d3 global, even if you load them independently; thus, code you write is the same whether or not you use the default bundle.

So your code should be either like this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
    <script>console.log(d3)</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3dxuvjke/2/

or like this:

```
<html>
<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.5/require.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script> -->
    <script>
    require.config({
      paths: {
        d3: "https://d3js.org/d3.v4"
      }
    });

    require(['d3'], function(d3){
      console.log(d3)
    })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3dxuvjke/